# using timeit functions with len functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to calculate the program's runtime . How do I use timeit functions with len functions in this code.

code:

```
import timeit
def shellSort(alist):
    sublistcount = len(alist)//2
    while sublistcount > 0:

      for startposition in range(sublistcount):
        gapInsertionSort(alist,startposition,sublistcount)

      print("After increments of size",sublistcount,"The list is",alist)


      sublistcount = sublistcount // 2

def gapInsertionSort(alist,start,gap):
    for i in range(start+gap,len(alist),gap):

        currentvalue = alist[i]
        position = i

        while position>=gap and alist[position-gap]>currentvalue:
            alist[position]=alist[position-gap]
            position = position-gap

        alist[position]=currentvalue
    return alist
alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
shellSort(alist)
print(alist)
print(timeit.timeit("[len(alist)]","from__main__import shellSort"))
```

error given by the program:

```
After increments of size 4 The list is [20, 26, 44, 17, 54, 31, 93, 55, 77]

After increments of size 2 The list is [20, 17, 44, 26, 54, 31, 77, 55, 93]

After increments of size 1 The list is [17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]

[17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Mervee/Desktop/shell sort.py", line 29, in <module>

    print(timeit.timeit("[len(alist)]","from__main__import shellSort"))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\timeit.py", line 213, in timeit

    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer).timeit(number)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\timeit.py", line 122, in __init__

    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")

  File "<timeit-src>", line 3

    from__main__import shellSort

                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hi @merve, welcome to stackoverflow. I did this for you, but the next time: The editor has a really nice feature called code formatting that you can use to ... format code by selecting it and clicking on `{}`.

Comment: You wanted to write `from __main__ import shellSort`

Comment: Note that you are measuring the wrong thing here; measuring the speed of `len()` is not going to tell you anything about your sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have a syntax error in the line python complains about; it's always

```
from module import things
```

note that the spaces are important.

Answer (score 0):

> To give the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module access to functions you define, you can pass a `setup` parameter which contains an import statement:

example:

```
def test():
    """Stupid test function"""
    L = []
    for i in range(100):
        L.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("test()", setup="from __main__ import test"))
```

and in your case, you need to pass the name of your function to calculate the program's runtime :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("shellSort()", setup="from__main__import shellSort"))
```